# How to Extract URL for KODI playlist

Tags: ios, objective-c, kodi

I am trying to extract the URL to use in xbmc from a stream. The stream is live so there are no files being downloaded.Any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but...you could get [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to trace the stream url.
And then save it as a .strm file or a m3u or pls list as shown [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/Internet_video_and_audio_streams).